# Alias not working on Apache2.4

Tags: alias, apache2.4

I have upgraded from an earlier Apache2 to the latest Apache 2.4.  My previous setup had the following alias in default.conf file in the sites-available directory:

```
Alias /weewx /home/weewx/public_html
<Directory "/home/weewx/public_html">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

In the new Apache 2.4 setup I have added the following to 000-default.conf in sites-available:

```
Alias /weewx /home/weewx/public_html

<Directory /home/weewx/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
```

But now I get a 403 error - "you don't have permission to access /weewx on this server".  I have tried moving my new Alias and Directory entry into the alias.conf file in the mods-available directory, but that still give the 404 error.

Is there something wrong with my Directory entry, or are the Alias and Directory in the wrong place?

Answer (score 6):

You need to add

```
Require all granted
```

to your new Directory container to grant access to this directory. That replaces the old

```
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

See [the Apache documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/access.html) for more about this.

Answer (score 4):

All alias's in apache 2.4 have to be configured in the /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/alias.conf file they are ignored in the virtual host files.

Comment: This is not true. In Apache 2.4.25 an [Alias directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html) can be configured in a Virtualhost.